# Porting a JavaService app (Windows Service) to run on Websphere - best parent class?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, windows-services, type-signature

I've been asked to port an existing Java app that runs as a windows service to run on Websphere. It is implemented using [JavaService.exe](http://javaservice.ow2.org/docs/devdocs/javacode.html) and a [stop_method](http://javaservice.ow2.org/docs/devdocs/devcmds.html)

The type signature of the parent service class is:

```
public abstract class ParentService {
    public static void main(String args[]);
    public void requestStop();      
}
```

Note that the `main` method in the example above is the equivalent of the `init` method in a servlet (although it is static) - it is used for the same purpose.

What is the equivalent parent class for a continuously running object in the J2EE standard (or even in the Websphere custom standards?)

Comment: The question is a little bit too broad: What is happening in the `main` method called by JavaService.exe? Is it something like job scheduling, a server listening on a socket or queue etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the big idea is mapping an `init` and a `shutdown` method to a Java interfaces in the Enterprise standards...

It turns out there are [four alternatives](http://blog.eisele.net/2010/12/seven-ways-to-get-things-started-java.html) (and three vendor specific ones):

1. EJB 3.1 @Startup
2. Startup Servlet
3. ServletContextListener
4. [Resource Adapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/resource/spi/ResourceAdapter.html) to Perform as a Startup Class